# How to use Facebook geo targeting programmatically?

Tags: api, facebook, geolocation

I can't seem to find how to do [geo targeting](http://www.rockyfu.com/blog/facebook-fan-pages-geotargeting/) (filtering a post based on the location of a user) on facebook using their API.

Does anyone already managed to do it?

---

This is how you can do it via their interface:

[alt text http://www.rockyfu.com/rfpwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/facebook-page-targeting.jpg](http://www.rockyfu.com/rfpwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/facebook-page-targeting.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible with the current API, (only the front-end) but is anticipated to be added in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting via the Graph API was made available in late 2010.  Here's the blog post:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/434/

And docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/